# Clips explode$ used in function to make user input an integer

Tags: function, clips

I currently try to design a decision tree that consists of defrules and binds either question or prints conclusion depending on the answers provided by the user in Clips.

What I am trying to do in WX clips currently is for the user to input a value - number and depending on the number given, print out either a conclusion or ask another question.

Example:

```
(defrule potatoes-eaten?
  (vegetable-eaten "potato") ;this is the answer to the previous question
  =>
(bind ?reply (get-text-from-user "What is the total number of potatoes you have eaten?(please input integer value"))
(assert (potatoesEaten (explode$ ?potatoesEaten)))
)
```

Let's say if the person ate more than 10 potatoes, the conclusion will be a 'your belly will hurt, please consult with doctor'

If a person ate less than 10, and user input will be lower than 10 then I would like to assert another question.

Any clue on how I can do it?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the wxCLIPS function get-text-from-user returns a string (such as "10"), you need to modify your potatoes-eaten function so that the variable ?reply is provided as an argument rather than the variable ?potatoesEaten which was not previously assigned a value in the rule.

```
(defrule potatoes-eaten?
  (vegetable-eaten "potato") ;this is the answer to the previous question
  =>
  (bind ?reply (get-text-from-user "What is the total number of potatoes you have eaten?(please input integer value"))
  (assert (potatoesEaten (explode$ ?reply))))
```

You can then add some rules to process the response:

```
(defrule hurt-belly
   (potatoesEaten ?eaten&:(> ?eaten 10))
   =>
   ; Call the appropriate wxCLIPS function for displaying your message
   )

    (defrule no-hurt-belly
       (potatoesEaten ?eaten&:(<= ?eaten 10))
       =>
       ; next question
    )
```